c++ std::vector fails to be destructed with "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer"
I'm quite a newbie for gdb, so maybe the question is not valuable, but it really confused me. I found my code occasionally crash, the core dump file shows that the crash signal is SIGABRT, and the backtrace is
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (no_tid=0, signo=6, threadid=140188693307392) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
#1  __pthread_kill_internal (signo=6, threadid=140188693307392) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:78
#2  __GI___pthread_kill (threadid=140188693307392, signo=signo@entry=6) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89
#3  0x00007f8039485476 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/posix/raise.c:26
#4  0x00007f803946b7f3 in __GI_abort () at ./stdlib/abort.c:79
#5  0x00007f80394cc676 in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7f803961eb77 "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:155
#6  0x00007f80394e3cfc in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7f8039621210 "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer") at ./malloc/malloc.c:5664
#7  0x00007f80394e3fdc in munmap_chunk (p=<optimized out>) at ./malloc/malloc.c:3060
#8  0x00007f80394e849a in __GI___libc_free (mem=<optimized out>) at ./malloc/malloc.c:3381
#9  0x00007f7fbc5dd1c5 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate (__t=<optimized out>, __p=<optimized out>, this=0x7fff39d1adf0) at /usr/include/c++/11/ext/new_allocator.h:145
#10 std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::deallocate (__n=<optimized out>, __p=<optimized out>, __a=...) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/alloc_traits.h:496
#11 std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_deallocate (__n=<optimized out>, __p=<optimized out>, this=0x7fff39d1adf0) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:354
#12 std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::~_Vector_base (this=0x7fff39d1adf0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:335
#13 std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::~vector (this=0x7fff39d1adf0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:683
#14 FS::FSBuf::~FSBuf (this=0x7fff39d1adc0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /home/cmen/Projects-Code/acq_proc/src/acq_proc/cpp/include/fs/fs_basic.h:22
#15 0x00007f7fbc5dbf45 in FS::FSModule::run (this=this@entry=0x560cb230b8e0, flagPlotStatus=flagPlotStatus@entry=12...

notice that frame #6 shows the crash reason "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer", and we go to frame #15, which is at the last line of the function FS::FSModule::run, with i locals, I found that a local variable "FSBuf buf" contains vectors that cannot be accessed. FSBuf is a struct which contains some large vectors, all vectors would be assigned at FSBuf constructor to avoid memory assignment in the run time of calculating process. When I tried to p buf.xxx, some vectors are godd to be printed, for example
(gdb) p buf.comp
$48 = std::vector of length 1209600000, capacity 1209600000 = {6456, 7599, 6456, 0, 0, 0, 0, 280, -8, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 49304, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7676, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -4, 284, -19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 134, 17232, 134, 0, 0, 149, 126, -6, -1, 134, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 134, -2, -1, 0, 0, -4, 130, -3, 0, -3, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 134, -4, 0, 0, -2, 0, 0, 0, 5580, 22163, 5580, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...}

but some vectors cannot be accessed, for example
(gdb) p buf.conv
$49 = std::vector of length 30240000, capacity 30240000 = {Cannot access memory at address 0x7f77d3d93010

The FSBuf is like
struct FSBuf {
    std::vector<int32_t> comp;
    std::vector<float> conv;
    FSBuf::FSBuf(size_t comp_size, size_t conv_size);

And the construtor is like
FSBuf::FSBuf(size_t comp_size, size_t conv_size) :
    comp(comp_size),
    conv(conv_size) {}

What I want to know is, what are the probably reasons that a vector cannot be accessed? I checked the code, there is no mannully free or delete for the vectors in buf.
Or what infos do I need to get with some other gdb commands?

The problem might be in a totally different part of your program. E.g. you could have overwritten memory (of the vector) on the heap earlier, leading to issues later when you try to delete the vector.

When I encounter such issues, it's usually because of invalid index. Changing every operator[] of vector to .at() may give you a good starting point for the debug of your program.

Please show a [mre]

@AlanBirtles It's quite difficult because this bug cannot be reproduced stably, sometime it would occur in an hour, sometime it wouldn't occur in some days. In fact, I deployed the exactly same code in 4~5 servers, and only one server would get this bug about one or two days once, with serveral hundreds running per day, so I myself am also very confused.

@PepijnKramer I believe that. But since I'd never met a broken vector before, I'd like to know, when a vector cannot be accessed, it would be more likely it writes to other memory regions, or other things write to the vector region?

I suspect some other code overwriting part of the heap where the vector stores its information (e.g. pointers to the allocated memory).  Or even worse the heap data itself. These can be very tricky bugs to solve if your code base is large.

If you can't debug it with the code we don't stand much chance without it. You should enable sanitisers, ensure you have comprehensive unit tests etc.

@PepijnKramer Thank you for your kind reply, but it's strange that pointer to the allocated mem should be stored in stack IMO. Debugging is just so difficult.

@ChuangMen You cannot look at FSBuf just by itself -- I could easily write a program that uses FSBuf without any new or delete, and create a program that has mistakes in multiple places that misuses FSBuf causing the vectors to be invalid.  It doesn't even have to be a huge program.  For example, if FSBuf's are being stored in another vector, and I have a pointer or reference to a particular FSBuf in that vector, if that vector is resized, that pointer or reference can be invalidated.  I then keep using that pointer, that pointer value "looks good", but the object is invalid.

Sounds like you're indeed overwriting memory or deleting stuff too early if you're getting this crash inconsistently.

@PaulMcKenzie Thank you. In fact there are about 18 vectors in FSBuf, and the core dump file shows about 10 are crashed while 8 are normal. It's hard to dig out how so many vectors get crashed at one time occasionally. Anyway I'll try some other tools other than gdb and the core dump file.


What I want to know is, what are the probably reasons that a vector cannot be accessed?

Undefined behavior of some sort is the most common reason.
For any crash inside malloc implementation (which is what you have in your stack trace), there are really only two possible reasons:

a bug in the malloc implementation itself
heap corruption caused by a bug your program

Needless to say, in 99.999% of the instances of such crashes reason 2 is the cause.
Heap corruption bugs are very hard to debug using GDB, because the root cause can be 100s or 1000s of instructions removed from where the crash happens.
Fortunately, tools like Valgrind and Address Sanitizer can usually tell you exactly where the bug is.
